# How should I customize DropdownButtons and DropdownMenuItems in Flutter?

Tags: drop-down-menu, widget, dropdown, flutter

The default [DropdownButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) with DropdownMenuItems returns a light-grey dropdown. How should I customize the dropdown (e.g. background color, dropdown width)? I can change the `style` property in both DropdownButton and DropdownMenuItem, like this:

```
return new DropdownButton(
      value: ...,
      items: ...,
      onChanged: ...,
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
```

but this doesn't change the dropdown's background color.

Should I copy DropdownMenu and extend it? Does Flutter plan to add customization for this widget in the near future?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As Collin said, your `DropdownMenuItem` will follow your [`ThemeData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) class. Not only its `backgroundColor` will match the `canvasColor` in your `ThemeData` class, but also it will follow the same `TextStyle`.

So, for a quick example:

```
new ThemeData(
        fontFamily: "Encode Sans", //my custom font
        canvasColor: _turquoise, //my custom color
//other theme data)
```

Furthermore, if you want to control the `width` of the menu, you can feed its `child` property a new `Container` and add the desired `width`, check the following GIF, I started with `width: 100.0` then hot reloaded after changing it to `200.0`, notice how the `width` was manipulated, just make sure you use a suitable width so that you do not get overflow problems later on when you use the menu within a more complex layout.

[image]

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title:new Text ("Test"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new DropdownButton(items: new List.generate(20, (int index){
          return new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Container(
            child: new Text ("Item#$index"),
            width: 200.0, //200.0 to 100.0
          ));
        })
            , onChanged: null)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to override the padding (left and right) for each DropdownMenuItem? The ThemeData doesn't have a `padding` property. I tried setting my DropdownMenuItem's padding to negative but it's not allowed. Thanks!

Comment: @Mary `ThemeData` is about the visuals (coloring, text styling..etc) and not about positioning. I believe you want to center your items in the dropdown, so all you need to do is to wrap the `Text` widget in the answer within a `Center` widget. However, if you need to customize the positioning of the items such that they are not centered, you will need to wrap the `Text` widget inside a `Row` which is wrapped inside a `Padding` widget, and then customize the `padding` property as you want.

Comment: You can replace the `Row` in the previous comment with a `Container` as well, and you will achieve the same result, if there is anything that is not clear enough, please let me know.

Answer (score 91):

You can accomplish this by wrapping the [`DropdownButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) in a [`Theme`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) widget and overriding the [`canvasColor`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/canvasColor.html).

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _value = 42;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            canvasColor: Colors.blue.shade200,
          ),
          child: new DropdownButton(
            value: _value,
            items: <DropdownMenuItem<int>>[
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text('Foo'),
                value: 0,
              ),
              new DropdownMenuItem(
                child: new Text('Bar'),
                value: 42,
              ),
            ],
            onChanged: (int value) {
              setState(() {
                _value = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck on this until I found this answer!

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. It looks like its been an issue for some time: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17414

Comment: you can also do ```data: ThemeData.dark(),``` in the Theme and it will let you have the white / dark drop down or data: ThemeData.light()

Comment: @Zuriel: you don't even need to do that. You can change the dark or light Theme in the MaterialApp.

Answer (score 68):

I was able to change the background for the Dropdown by wrapping it in a `Container` with the `color` property set.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Here's the code:

Define these values in the widget state:

```
final items = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];
String selectedValue = 'Four';
```

then use this code

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),

  // dropdown below..
  child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedValue,
      onChanged: (String newValue) =>
        setState(() => selectedValue = newValue),
      items: items
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
              (String value) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  ))
          .toList(),

      // add extra sugar..
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      iconSize: 42,
      underline: SizedBox(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is best example what i am looking for

Comment: It almost saves my day, but in DropdownButtonFormField this covers the validation section too not only the field.

Comment: this was the only real solution I could find. First I found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135853/how-to-create-a-rounded-corner-of-dropdownbuttonformfield-flutter/66136773 but this is much more elegant than those 1500 lines of code. Wrapping it in a container I can get rounded edges on the button and the drop down menu list. Its clunky for sure, as I'm simulating what should be possible natively, but sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: is there required to define variable - dropdownValue

Comment: @CrazyMind if you don't define it, the dropdown won't change when an item is selected.

Answer (score 16):

You can do something very simple in the latest version of Flutter.

The DropdownButton class has an inbuilt variable called 'dropdownColor' which can be assigned any color you need directly, without changing any 'ThemeData'. Automatically changes the color of the dropdown menu items as well.

Comment: I have big application which has more than 50 dropdownbuttonformfield. So I cannot change them one-by-one. Its very time consuming work. Can we do it by adding a global themedata? If yes, please suggest, how can we do. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you want the DropdownButton to fill the space that it is in, use the property `isExpanded` and set it to `true`

```
DropdownButton<String>(
   isExpanded: true,
)
```

Comment: Not relevant to the question.

Comment: I wrapped the dropdownbutton with a container and set the containers color

Answer (score 14):

Use this for color

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(
              items: null,
              onChanged: null,
              dropdownColor: Colors.red,
            ),
```

Comment: I have big application which has more than 50 dropdownbuttonformfield. So I cannot change them one-by-one. Its very time consuming work. Can we do it by adding a global themedata? If yes, please suggest, how can we do. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh you can also create a reusable custom dropdown.

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. Yes, we can develop reusable custom dropdown but we still have to replace it on more than 50 existing dropdownbuttonformfield elements in the app. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/style.html will help you to figure out some stylings.

```
DropdownButton(
  dropdownColor: Colors.grey,
  value: this.repeatType,
  onChanged: (String? value) {
    print(value);
    setState(() {
      this.repeatType = value!;
    });
  },
  selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
    return this.repeatTypes.map((String value) {
      return Text(
        this.repeatType,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
    }).toList();
  },
  items: this
      .repeatTypes
      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(
              item,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            ),
            value: item,
          ))
      .toList())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it with container like this:

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)
  ),
  child: DropdownButton(
    dropdownColor: Colors.white,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    value: 'ar',
    items: [
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('English'), value: 'en'),
      DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('العربية'), value: 'ar'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) package.
You can use the dropdownDecoration property to customize the dropdown menu appearance. This is the best package I found to fully customize a DropdownButton

Answer (score 1):

**To create own custom drop down widget you can use below code
value - selected dropdown value
items - list of dropdownitem you can pass
onChanged - pass function that will be invoked when you select from dropdown**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class SDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String value;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items;
  final Function(String?)? onChanged;
  const SDropDown[enter image description here][1](
      {Key? key, required this.value, required this.items, this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SDropDownState createState() => _SDropDownState();
}

class _SDropDownState extends State<SDropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 3),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        isExpanded: true,
        value: widget.value,
        items: widget.items,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        underline: const SizedBox(),
        dropdownColor: theme.primaryColor,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple now,
Just use the `dropdownColor` property inside the `DropdownButton` widget like this:

```
DropdownButton(
    dropdownColor: Colors.red,  // here you change the background color
    value: 'Your value',
    items: [ ],
)
```