# How to add different textstyle for dropdownmenuitem and item selected in dropdown in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, text-styling, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am new application development. How can I add individual textstyles for a dropdown in flutter like i need to add black textcolor for dropdownmenuitems and white textcolor for the selected value in dropdown ?

Comment: Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530527/how-should-i-customize-dropdownbuttons-and-dropdownmenuitems-in-flutter)
Please use the search function first.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use :

```
DropdownButton(
//Use style for dropdown text color
   style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.blue,
    fontSize: 15,
  ),
  // use dropdownColor for color of flutter dropdown
  dropdownColor:Colors.green,
  //below is the hint of your dropdown
  hint: Text(
       'Select Month',
        style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 15,
      ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
),
```