# Change background color of dropdown button- flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I want  to change the background color and border radius of `DropDownButton`,

i have tried it with `theme` but it changes the color of dropdown list not the button.

```
 Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.blue),
          child: DropdownButton(
                     items: [DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('one'))],
                     onChanged: (newvlaue) {}),
                        )
```

what i want:
[image]

what i get:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I customize DropdownButtons and DropdownMenuItems in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46530527/how-should-i-customize-dropdownbuttons-and-dropdownmenuitems-in-flutter)

Comment: @tomerpacific no, they are changing background color of dropdown list not the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the color of the button and add a radius you can wrap the dropdown button with a container.

[image: dropdown button wrapped with a container]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change dropdownbutton background color then

in DropdownButton2 properties

`dropdownStyleData : DropdownStyleData(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: chooseYourColor))`

also you can customize border color, border radius for using BoxDecoration